Is it me or is $ \frac{x}{\log_\pi{x}}$ a better approximation for $\pi(x)$ than $\frac{x}{\ln{x}}$?
$\pi$ approximation" />
I know it has been proven that $\pi(x)$ approaches $\frac{x}{\ln(x)}$ as $x$ becomes very large, but for small values, why is $\frac{x}{\log_\pi(x)}$  a better approximation? Is it because it's $\pi$ or because $\pi$ is close to some special number, or is it just a coincidence?

But look at the graph!

Nope.

For small numbers , $x/ln(x)$ is not a very good approximation , so it is not very difficult to beat it in small ranges. And the range you chose has extremely small values.

Evaluation of $\pi(x)$ at small values of $x$ is very misleading as $\operatorname{li}(x)$ is considered a better estimate than $\frac{x}{\log(x)}$ and $\pi(x)−\operatorname{li}(x)$ is known to change sign infinitely many times (see More precise estimates).

For prime number estimates small $n$ doesn't necessarily paint the right picture. Skewes's number is a standard example.

I haven't looked too much into this, but since $x/\ln x$ estimates $\pi(x)$ from below, chances are that whatever $\alpha>1$ and close to $1$ you take, $\lvert \pi(x)-\alpha x/\ln (x)\rvert<\lvert \pi(x)-x/\ln x\rvert$ for a while, until it stops when the approximation of $\alpha \pi(x)$ becomes relevant. I doubt $\alpha=\ln \pi$ has any maximizing property.
